# How to extract both content and markup in a class?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract the content marked by `<div class="sense">` in `abc`. With `''.join(map(str, soup.select_one('.sense').contents))`, I only get the content between markers, i.e `xyz`. To fulfill my job, I also need the full `<div class="sense">xyz</div>`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

abc = """abcdd<div class="sense">xyz</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(abc, 'html.parser')

content1 = ''.join(map(str, soup.select_one('.sense').contents))

print(content1)
```

and the result is `xyz`. Could you please elaborate on how to achieve my goal?

Comment: This should work `content1 = soup.select_one('.sense')`

Comment: Thank you @KunduK. I've just tried your command (with a complete html) and it works very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

abc = """abcdd<div class="sense">xyz</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(abc, 'html.parser')

div = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'sense'})

print(div)
```

prints:

```
<div class="sense">xyz</div>
```